# javascript serializing question

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I'm using the following...

```
 // (jquery / pseudo code)
 var base = $('form[name="gs"]').attr('action');
 var params = $('form[name="gs"]').serialize();
 var url = base + '?' + params;
```

I have a listener which calls this function when a key is pressed. It's grabbing a query in a search bar. However, if  type more in the search box after it has already executed once it returns a result of undefined. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Declare global variables outside the function:

```
var globalBase, globalParams;
```

Then cache the values the initial time and update them accordingly:

```
globalBase   = (globalBase === void(0)) ? 
               $('form[name="gs"]').attr('action') : 
               globalBase;
globalParams = (globalParams === void(0)) ?
               $('form[name="gs"]').serialize() : 
               globalParams;
var url      = globalBase + '?' + globalParams;
```

If you need to update the base or params based on what is typed on key press, then you can replace the else statements with something like `$(yourInput).val()`.

Comment: `globalBase === void 0` is a nicer check.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that shortcut (obv)

Comment: For clarification `void (expression)` runs an expression and returns undefined. I'm not too certain about scoping wrt to the expression but `void 0` or `void (0)` just returns `undefined`

Comment: Having problems making this work. First, it doesn't work at all first time round and then with the listener it doesn't either.. what would `$(yourInput)` be? :S